# Change order shipping address for a custom product type in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want set an alternative address if the cart has a product type that is equal on a specific type.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'mbm_alter_shipping', 10, 1 );
function mbm_alter_shipping ($order) {
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    foreach($items as $product => $values) { 
        $product->get_product(); 
        if ($product->is_type('octopus')) {
    $address = array(
        'company'    => 'Test',
        'email'      => 'test@test.com',
        'phone'      => '777-777-777-777',
        'city'       => 'London',
        'state'      => '',
        'postcode'   => '12345',
        'country'    => 'UK'
        );
    }
$order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

  }
  return $order;
}
?>
```

But when trying to place an order, I get an Internal Server Error and the order is not placed.

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _“Who can help me to make this functional?”_ - the error log, because it can tell you what the _actual_ error is. So go check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` is an action hook, your code is outdated and full of mistakes…  Try to use the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'alter_order_shipping_address', 10, 2 );
function alter_order_shipping_address( $order, $data ) {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) { 
        // Targetting a custom product type
        if ( $cart_item['data']->is_type('octopus') ) {
            // Changing shipping address
            $order->set_address( array(
                'company'    => 'Test',
                'email'      => 'test@test.com',
                'phone'      => '777-777-777-777',
                'city'       => 'London',
                'state'      => '',
                'postcode'   => '12345',
                'country'    => 'UK'
            ), 'shipping' );
            
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.